# How to call php variable from another php page

Tags: php, database, global-variables, session-variables

Hi I have three step of form php pages, Form1 user will fill out data and carry this variable to the Form2 page and perform the Database{Insert,Update}.And again Form2 pass their variable which users is fill out and also Form1 variable to the form3.My problem is how to pass Form1 Variable to the Form3.

*Form2*

```
//variable from Form1
$calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id']; 
$calendar_name = $_GET['$calendar_choose_name'];
$calendar_type = $_GET['calendar_type'];
```

Then Perfrom Database Select and show the result to the Form2.After user select and fill form2 .Pass the variable to the Form3.

*Form3*

```
$current_month =  $_GET['month']; //Variable from Form2
```

I try to call Form1 Variable with SESSION

```
$_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] = $_GET["calendar_id_val"];
$calendar_id = $_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] ;
```

But it dosen't work. How to call Form1 Variable From Form3. I used GET method .

Comment: hidden fields or sessions. If you're using sessions, make sure you use `session_start();` before trying to access/set any session variables.

Comment: You have to set the session. use `session_start()` to start using a session. Read this about sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: $_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] = $calendar_id_val; 
and do start session.
in Form3 why are you fetching calendar_id_val using $_GET and storing in $_SESSION. are you sending from Form2 the calendar_id_val value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to quite understand how long the variables stay in memory. In PHP, once the script has finished, every memory that was allocated by that script is freed, so `$calendar_id_val` is no longer in memory.
If you want to use values from a form when next the user posts a form (the next request made), then you're already half-way there, try:

```
session_start();
$calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id'];
$_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] = $calender_id_val;
```

Before you can use the session, you'll always have to call `session_start`. Assuming there's no need to keep the data around after you're finished processing the third form, `session_destroy` is worth a look. But anyhow, after storing the data in the session, the id value will be available to you as long as the session is valid. [check the manual for more on sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).
You could use a cookie, too. Since you're using GET, I take it you're not passing any sensitive or crucial data anyway, [so `setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) would do the job, too. Refer to the values using the `$_COOKIE` super-global, then.

Note that the use of Sessions is to be recommended, because sessions store the data server-side, whereas cookies are stored on the client's machine. This makes them vulnerable (can be tempered with) and unreliable (client can disable/reject your cookie)

As always, if I didn't link to all functions I mentioned, just go to `http://www.php.net/<functionName>` for details

Answer (score 0):

Put `session_start();` into your page top 1row 1 column

```
session_start();
$calendar_id_val = $_GET['calendar_id'];
$_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] = $calender_id_val;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should start the session before you using it.

assign the session variables in form1 page like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] = $_GET["calendar_id_val"];
$calendar_id = $_SESSION['calendar_id_val'] ;
```

and access the session variables in form2 page like this

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['calendar_id_val'];
```

.

Comment: instead of copying existing answers, upvote them if you agree, or leave it at that... but what did you _add_ to the existing answers that wasn't said before?

Comment: ?? Your comment reads _"@Elias Van Ootegem"_... what am I to make of that?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to declare it as global.

```
global $a;
$a = $_GET['really'];
```